# Conflicting Jquery Issue I'm stumped on

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having an issue with conflicting jquery that I can't figure out...

I have a slider script, and a hover image script that work fine, but not together.

I got one to work when I add a noconclict script, but for some reason the other STILL is not coming through and I've tired tons of things and still get an "object undefined" error in chrome.

Can somone please possibly take a look and help me out?  Thanks!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script><!--script for tooltip-->        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery.ipicture.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>




   <script>
$(".fade").hide(0).delay(50).fadeIn(1000)
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
          if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                            //change the button label to be 'Show'
            toggle_switch.html('Show');
          }else{
                            //change the button label to be 'Hide'
            toggle_switch.html('Hide');
          }
        });
      });

    }); 
    </script>


<script>
 $.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                slideshow: "true",
                animation: "slide"
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: *what* "object undefined" error? That's really important here. If they're both jQuery scripts, `noConflict` has no relation. That allows jQuery to work with another library that uses `$`

Comment: But why are you including two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: @helion3 You can use `noconflict` to work with different versions of jquery as well.

Comment: Right, I missed that he was using two copies.

Comment: So, as Kapa said, why are you including two different versions?  The newest one should cover the older one.  Then you shouldn't get any conflicts

Comment: Well I have to use the older one because using 1.10 only (which the slider works with) does not work with the rollover jquery.. I've tried a few times and it only works with 1.8.  I've ran into this similar issue before and it's always a mess to get them to not conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress you shouldn't be including jQuery / JS files directly.

You appear to be including jQuery twice as well. 1.10.2 and 1.8.3.

Enqueue them in functions.php:

```
function wpse_load_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'ipicture', get_template_dirctory_uri() . '/library/js/jquery.ipicture.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ipicture' );

    wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_template_dirctory_uri() . '/library/js/jquery.flexslider.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_jquery' );
```

Then put all your code inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   // jquery code
});
```

Comment: @Andy that edit was clearly invalid and you turned it into 2 edits :/ both reviewers before you rejected it.

Comment: @OGHaza Eh-up, I mistook it for a question. Apologies and thanks for reverting.

Comment: I'm confused how you could enque jquery in the functions file?  that code above doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: It's how jQuery is loaded in WordPress. Many themes / plugins use jQuery so if they all included it when they wanted there would be conflicts like you're seeing now when you've tried to include it. I'll add the code you need to load it.

Comment: Holy shnikies, that worked!  I just needed to pust the code you put int he enqueue script portion in my functions.php file as you mentioned.  Thanks for your help, you guys made my week!